Post persian character value with delphi TREST component
I send a post request with Delphi TREST component with parameter value as Persian characters:
Request.Method := rmPost;
Request.Parameter.Name := 'ChangeLog';
Request.Parameter.Value:= 'توضیحات نسخه';
Request.Parameter.Type := pkGETorPOST;

but the value of the parameter (توضیحات نسخه)  post as below
bAd8c6lCbDb7bA d6c3bEd7

What should I do to post the value same توضیحات نسخه ?
What would the solution with the TREST component be?

Can you provide more context about where exactly you are seeing this post data?

the backend is .netCore and database is MSSQLServer.
i send this request and backend save ChangeLog parameter into DB.
when send request to server to get whatever saved in DB result is bAd8c6lCbDb7bA d6c3bEd7

Finally I send the ASCII code instead Actual Persian characters and Convert ASCII Characters to Actual Characters, But I Want to find out why my characters change to bAd8c6lCbDb7bA d6c3bEd7 and what should I do to fix that.

What you showed is not how http/rest posts data. Are you sure it is not more like %bA%d8... instead? That would make more sense, and is common for non-ASCII characters

i used a trick, i send ascii code to server instead characters(persian text) and in the client convert ascii code to characters and my problem solve.
